# Pandas percentage of total row within multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Foo','A','Green',10,20],['Foo','A','Red',20,30],['Foo','A','Total',50,60],['Foo','B','Blue',5,10],['Foo','B','Red',15,25],['Foo','B','Total',40,100],['Foo','C','Orange',25,8],['Foo','C','Total',50,10]],columns = ['Default','Letter','Color','Value'])
print df

      Default Letter   Color  Value  Value2
0     Foo      A   Green     10      20
1     Foo      A     Red     20      30
2     Foo      A   Total     50      60
3     Foo      B    Blue      5      10
4     Foo      B     Red     15      25
5     Foo      B   Total     40     100
6     Foo      C  Orange     25       8
7     Foo      C   Total     50      10
```

**I need to find the percentage of the total row that each color makes up within each group**

My first thought was to split them into separate indexes, and use .div, but in this case I have a multiindex (I know in my example the first all says Foo, but that's not how the real data looks - roll with it.) and I get the notImplemented Error.

```
df_color = df[df['Color']!='Total'].set_index(['Default','Letter','Color'])
df_tot = df[df['Color']=='Total'].drop(['Color'],axis = 1).set_index(['Default','Letter'])

df_out = df_color.div(df_tot)

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-0caf0e2959a6> in <module>()
      4 df_tot = df[df['Color']=='Total'].drop(['Color'],axis = 1).set_index(['Default','Letter'])
      5 
----> 6 df_out = df_color.div(df_tot)
      7 #df.set_index(['Default','Letter','Color'],inplace = True)...
```

Here is my desired output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([['Foo','A','Green',.2,.333],['Foo','A','Red',.4,.5],['Foo','B','Blue',.125,.1],['Foo','B','Red',.375,.25],['Foo','C','Orange',.5,.8]],columns = ['Default','Letter','Color','Value','Value2'])
​
print df_out
df_out = pd.DataFrame([['Foo','A','Green',.2,.333],['Foo','A','Red',.4,.5],['Foo','B','Blue',.125,.1],['Foo','B','Red',.375,.25],['Foo','C','Orange',.5,.8]],columns = ['Default','Letter','Color','Value','Value2'])
```

**EDIT** note that there are actually multiple value columns - for simplicity I just show one here, but the solution needs to handle 50-100 numerical value columns.

Comment: When you say "multiple value columns" do you mean that there are columns `Value1`, `Value2`, ..., `ValueN`? And for each one of those you want an average inside each group (as partitioned by the column `Color`)?

Comment: Can you post a representative example? Here are the SO guidelines on [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added an extra column. yes, in actuality the value columns are months, so I need the % within each month. I don't want to have to iterate over every column, I'm looking for a vectorized solution.

Comment: Give data that is similar to your real data to help people...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Checkout [the tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) on using groupby.

**Note**: this implementation assumes that the `Total` entry for each color is the last one for that color (as in the example) but this is easily modifiable.

```
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x not  in ['Default', 'Letter', 'Color']]  # or df.columns[3:]
df.loc[:, cols] = df.groupby('Letter', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df[cols] / df[cols].iloc[-1])
df[~(df['Color'] == 'Total')]
```

returns

```
  Default Letter   Color  Value    Value2
0     Foo      A   Green  0.200  0.333333
1     Foo      A     Red  0.400  0.500000
3     Foo      B    Blue  0.125  0.100000
4     Foo      B     Red  0.375  0.250000
6     Foo      C  Orange  0.500  0.800000
```

Comment: In actuality there are multiple value columns, so I don't want to do an apply function multiple times.

Comment: While I agree groupby on the fly is the better way to do this and can be presented as an option, this does not address the issue presented in the question.

Comment: @AndrewL I must be misunderstanding something. What does this not address?

Comment: @flyingmeatball you don't need to apply it multiple times... the division broadcasting will take care of it. If you post an example DataFrame that illustrates what you are talking about that would be helpful.

Comment: @andrewL - You do need to apply it multiple times using your logic - you explicitly call df['Value'] / df.iloc[-1, -1]. I'm looking for a vectorized solution, not one that relies on calling df['column'], because there are many of them and it will be exceedingly slow to do it that way.

Comment: @flyingmeatball was that last comment addressed to me? I've updated the solution to show how this is extensible to your updated example.

Comment: @alex yes - you've still hardcoded the columns, you just moved it to a list. Point is columns need to be dynamic. I went with the solution I posted below - doesn't rely on specific column names being provided.

Comment: @flyingmeatball Maybe I'm missing something but in your solution you do call out `['Default','Letter', 'Color']` and then operate on all the others.

Comment: @Alex I identified those because they are ID columns, I'm talking about your line cols = ['Value', 'Value2']. You have hardcoded which columns contain values and need to be switched to percentages. The goal is for those to be dynamic (I don't know at run time what the columns I need to convert to percentages will be, but I do know all of the columns used to identify my unique groups (['Default','Letter','Color'])

Comment: @flyingmeatball then just pick out the columns that are not in that list dynamically... that's just a normal Python thing. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reformatting the datafames using the melt function so the column name became another column in the data. Then I could simply merge and divide, and reformat at the end

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Foo','A','Green',10,20],['Foo','A','Red',20,30],['Foo','A','Total',50,60],['Foo','B','Blue',5,10],['Foo','B','Red',15,25],['Foo','B','Total',40,100],['Foo','C','Orange',25,8],['Foo','C','Total',50,10]],columns = ['Default','Letter','Color','Value','Value2'])

df_color = df[df['Color']!='Total']
df_tot = df[df['Color']=='Total'].drop(['Color'],axis = 1)

df_melt = pd.melt(df_color,id_vars = ['Default','Letter', 'Color'],var_name =['value_field'] )
df_tot_melt = pd.melt(df_tot,id_vars = ['Default','Letter'],var_name =['value_field'], value_name = 'Total')


df_melt_pct = pd.merge(df_melt, df_tot_melt, how = 'outer', on = ['Default','Letter','value_field'])
df_melt_pct['Pct'] = df_melt_pct['value'] /df_melt_pct['Total']
df_melt_pct = df_melt_pct.drop(['value','Total'],axis = 1).set_index(['Default','Letter','Color','value_field']).unstack()
df_melt_pct.columns = df_melt_pct.columns.droplevel(0)

print df_melt_pct

value_field            Value    Value2
Default Letter Color                  
Foo     A      Green   0.200  0.333333
               Red     0.400  0.500000
        B      Blue    0.125  0.100000
               Red     0.375  0.250000
        C      Orange  0.500  0.800000
```